# Can the html5 canvas give a screenshot to any dom element?

Tags: html, dom, screenshot, html5-canvas

I know the canvas's drawimage method could draw HTMLImageElement,HTMLCanvasElement,HTMLVideoElement

but if I want draw a screenshot of a div container?

I know the html2canvas library，however I don't quite understand it's document and it API,I think it does't flexible.So I want write one by myself?How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very simple. You have to recursively iterate through all the child nodes, determine their computed styles and paint their representations manually.

For example, something like

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red; background: blue;">foo</div>
```

requires the following steps:

- Determine `div`'s dimensions and position (`getComputedStyle`)
- paint a blue filled rectangle accordingly
- paint a red rectangle outline accordingly
- Determine computed font style and padding
- Add the "foo" text with that position and style

This is basically what html2canvas does, and there is no native canvas API to do it.